# Gitlab Runners on Fargate not working with custom image

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have been trying really hard to create a docker image to be used in the fargate task so this will serves as runners for us but it is really impossible to do
i followed this guid https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/runner_autoscale_aws_fargate/
but if i want to create my own docker image (to replace the exemple in this guid )
the manger EC2 runner is just unable to connect to the task no matter what i tried
Please assist

I think that my problem is that i am not using the correct machnizem to create SSH keys
what i did is creating SSH keys on the manager EC2 instance and i am passing the public key to the the Fargate task
with an environment variable on the task
The "registry.gitlab.com/tmaczukin-test-projects/fargate-driver-debian:latest" Image is some how creating the ENV var by itself
and i have no idea how and how to do it on my custom image

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem 
first of all i was building the image on the apple chip which is arm64 and the fargate is running on amd64 so i needed to run the commend :
"docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64 -f ./Dockerfile -t repo-name:tag ."
so this is one issue 
the other issue is that i didnt give the task execution rile the permissions to pull from the AWS ECR service 
thanks for all the assistance